# Shorten URL of WCF Service

Tags: wcf

I have a simple service and the URL is being generated as:

```
http://localhost:1234/TestService/TestService.svc
```

Is there any way to get this to be:

```
http://localhost:1234/TestService.svc
```

i.e. to remove the Project name from the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the endpoint is implemented in code then you specify the URL in the call to `ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(...)`.

If the endpoint is implemented via configuration then in either the Web or App config look under elements `<services><service><host><baseAddresses>` and `<services><service><endpoint address=''>`.

The second is the relative address and will be appended to the base address.

Comment: My apologies, this is (at the moment) visual studio hosted.

Comment: There must be an App.config somewhere with the URL.

Comment: There is...but I'm looking at an example app from someone else that doesn't have anything obvious in the Web.config...but doesn't put the project name in the URL?

Comment: @BlueChippy, I've updated the response with some information. I hope that helps.